Retrieving a Single Numeric Device ID from a Mongoose Schema
How can I retrieve the deviceId as a single numeric value in my Mongoose schema and Express.js controller?
I'm using Mongoose with Express.js to save car records, and I've defined a deviceId field as a SchemaTypes.Long to accommodate large numbers. After saving a record, the response includes the deviceId as an object with low, high, and unsigned properties. However, I need to retrieve this value as a single, numeric value.
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);
var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  deviceId: { type: SchemaTypes.Long, required: true, unique: true }
}, { versionKey: false, virtuals: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("car", carSchema);

exports.carDemo = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const car = await Car.create(req.body);
  res.status(statusCode.OK).json(
    car
  );
});

I expect the response to include the deviceId as a single numeric value, similar to how it was provided in the request body.
API Response
response body
Expected
{
    "name": "I20",
    "deviceId":997786565423234,
    "_id":"66cf265cdcd77799f701efef"
}


Why because it will be initially in BSON object, You need to use toNumber method to get that representation.
res.status(statusCode.OK).json(
   ...car,
   deviceId : car.deviceId.toNumber()
);

